# How to hide something completely on mobile

Tags: mobile, media-queries, hide

I wonder how you can hide something completely, but **only** when you're browsing on your mobile.

In my case, I would like to hide this menu so it won't show up on any phones when browsing on my website.

https://jsfiddle.net/`0ephpwgj/`

Answer (score 0):

You can do using media queries as in 
https://jsfiddle.net/0ephpwgj/1/

```
@media(max-width:720px){
 .mobile-hide {
   display: none;
 }
}
```

you can change the max-width depending on the mobile device